# source the current file

Tags: vimrc, command-line

I know that to source my current file I need to do this:

```
 :so ~/.vimrc
```

But is it possible to source the current file without mentioning its name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:so %`

`%` refers the current buffer's filename. This works not just for `:source`, but for all of the commandline; see [`:help cmdline-special`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-special).